# ImportError: No module named 'paramiko'

Tags: python, python-3.x, paramiko

I have done through the other questions online here, and I feel that mine is different enough to warrant a new question.

So I have a `Centos 6 box`, which is running a small website for me, acts as an office git server and I am trying to configure `Python3` on it.

So I followed the following [these steps](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-python-2-7-6-and-3-3-3-on-centos-6-4) to set up `python3` on the server. However it seems that I cannot import paramiko into my script.

I downloaded the paramiko rpm however I get this message:

When I try to import paramiko I get:

```
[root@GIT Python-3.4.2]# rpm -ivh /usr/lib/Python-3.4.2/Modules/python-paramiko-1.7.5-2.1.el6.noarch.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
package python-paramiko-1.7.5-2.1.el6.noarch is already installed
```

When I run python3 directly:

```
[root@GIT inserv_health_check]# python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Jan 21 2015, 06:28:04)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import paramiko
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'paramiko'
>>>
```

I am sure there is a simple solution to this problem perhaps the path is wrong, or I should have put a symbolic link in somewhere.  Any help would be appreciated :)

Before anyone asks, which python output:

```
[root@GIT Python-3.4.2]# which python
/usr/bin/python
[root@GIT Python-3.4.2]# which pytho~n3
/usr/bin/which: no pytho~n3 in (/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)
[root@GIT Python-3.4.2]# which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to do `pip install paramiko` so that python sees that module. If you work on a virtual environment, you need to `workon <env_name>` first and then `pip install` the desired module.

Comment: pip install paramiko, I got the following error:

   error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Rolling back uninstall of pycrypto
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-root/pycrypto/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-w6kSsj-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-root/pycrypto
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log

Comment: Also:

Package gcc-4.4.7-11.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Comment: run `sudo apt-get install libffi-dev` and `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev` and try again

Comment: It is a centos box, so its yum not apt-get :)  Ran both commands got the response, nothing to do :(

Answer (score 6):

type `pip3 install paramiko`

if you want to install it for python3

Comment: pip3 install paramiko solved the issue in my case. Plain pip install paramiko didn't work.