# SparkSubmitOperator vs SSHOperator for submitting pyspark applications in airflow

Tags: airflow-scheduler, spark-submit, airflow, apache-spark-2.3

I have spark and airflow servers differently. And I don't have spark binary in airflow servers. I am able to use SSHOperator and run the spark jobs in cluster mode perfectly well. I would like to know what would be good using either SSHOperator or SparkSubmitOperator in a long run for submitting pyspark jobs. Any help would be appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Below are the pros and cons of using SSHOperator vs SparkSubmit Operator in airflow and my recommendation followed.

**SSHOperator :** This operator will perform SSH action into remote Spark server and execute the spark submit in remote cluster.

**Pros:**

1. No additional configuration required in the airflow workers

**Cons:**

1. Tough to maintain the spark configuration parameters
2. Need to enable SSH port 22 from airflow servers to spark servers which leads to security concerns ( though you are on private network its not a best practice to use SSH based remote execution.)

**SparkSubbmitOperator :** This operator will perform spark submit operation in clean way still you need to have additional infrastructure configuration.

**Pros:**

1. As mentioned above it comes with handy spark configuration and no additional effort to invoke spark submit

**Cons:**

1. Need to install spark on all airflow servers.

Apart from these 2 options I have listed additional 2 options.

1. Install Livy server on spark clusters and use python Livy library to interact with Spark servers from Airflow. Refer : https://pylivy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
2. If your spark clusters are on AWS EMR , I would encourage to using **EmrAddStepsOperator**

Refer here for additional discussions : [To run Spark Submit programs from a different cluster (1**.1*.0.21) in airflow (1**.1*.0.35). How to connect remotely other cluster in airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59552586/to-run-spark-submit-programs-from-a-different-cluster-1-1-0-21-in-airflow)

Answer (score 0):

SparkSubmitOperator is a specialized operator. That is, it should make writing tasks for submitting Spark jobs easier and the code itself more readable and maintainable. Therefore, I would use it if possible.

In your case, you should consider if the effort of modifying the infrastructure, such that you can use the SparkSubmitOperator, is worth the benefits, which I mentioned above.